# LWIP lockup on STM32

Tags: stm32, lwip

I have been having an issue in my project with LWIP. I am using a ST32F4 MCU and running with no OS. The network seems to run fine, the protocols all work, but then (usually a day or two later) the stack just stops running. It seems to happen when trying to make a new connection, but I can't confirm that because I haven't been able to locate what is causing it in the code.

Has anyone else come across this issue? I think it may be the same as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45935885/lwip-stm32-http-requests-failing).

Answer (score 0):

Do you call any LwIP functions from any interrupt-handlers, like UART etc?

How do you feed packets in/out of LwIP? Directly via interrupt handlers, or do you push them in from your "main-loop" ?

Lock-ups can also be signs of double free, or use-after-free of pbufs.

I also experiences that one project was unstable with wierd random locks-ups when running at the top-rated frequency of the STM32. If I clocked my STM32 at 100MHz instead of 120MHz, all my problems went away....